# F8 and F9 keys not being captured in Chrome with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to use some function keys as shortcuts to my web app. Everything seems to work, except that I can't capture F8 and F9 on chrome. I'm using jQuery 2.1, and am registering to the keydown event with:

```
$(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
    ...
};
```

I have made a very simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhpgomes/1t84hy9r/) to illustrate the problem. If I press any key, the text in the div is updated. Nothing happens if I press F8 or F9. I have tested on Firefox and it works, so it's a browser specific problem, even maybe some configuration in my machine.

My chrome's version is  37.0.2062.120 m

Another weird thing is that if I press F8 or F9 along with some modifier key (alt, shift or control), it works.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Show us how you're capturing the keys, for me it works just fine in Chrome -> **http://jsfiddle.net/utbsgnzu/1/**

Comment: hmm fiddle works for me in same version of chrome

Comment: It's working fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: Working for me as well. Does your keyboard have extra functions on the F8/F9 keys? Are you sure the focus is on the page when hitting those?

Comment: It works with F10, and any other F?, except F8/F9. I do believe it's something specific to my machine... some configuration or whatnot... but I can't figure out what... was hoping someone had some clue

Comment: And since it works in Firefox, I **think** it's not caused by the keyboard itself (having some extra function and such)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

I was running Chrome with the flag --disable-web-security, to allow CORS requests while in development. I restarted Chrome without the flag and everything started working.

Have no idea why, but will leave this here... maybe will help someone in the future.